# Could not switch between my NVIDIA and Intel HD graphics

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, intel-graphics

I tried to switch from Intel HD graphics to Nvidia but it always fails. I installed Nvidia-375 previously. Every time when I change the graphics, it shows:

[image]

I switched to Nvidia and reboot. It did not work at all.

Thanks so much!

Comment: Can you try running `sudo prime-select nvidia` from a terminal? Also what is the output of `lspci -k | grep -iEA3 'VGA|3D|Display'`?

Comment: When I run sudo prime-select nvidia it shows that :Info: the current GL alternatives in use are: ['mesa', None]
Info: the current EGL alternatives in use are: ['mesa-egl', None]
Error: the installed packages do not support PRIME
Error: nvidia mode can't be enabled

Comment: For  lspci -k | grep -iEA3 'VGA|3D|Display', it shows the two graphics cards. VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Device 591b (rev 04) and 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation Device 13b6 (rev a2)

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the *complete* output of both commands.